# What is wrong with this javascript closure?

Tags: javascript, recursion, closures, stack-trace

I have a recursive function (exploreNode)that updates the value of a variable (branch_queue) that is declared right above it.
When I run normally (without a closure function), it works as expected.

When I place inside of a closure function, the recursive function doesn't iterated through children nodes the way its supposed to. it remains on the same initial node, until a "Max Call Stack" error fires.

The purpose of the recursive function is to explore a JSON tree, until a desired ID is found. As it traverses through the tree, the branch_queue var is updated with the roadmap to the node of interest.

The closure was to not have the branch_queue as a global function.

I tried both in es6 and es5, thinking it could be a problem with scope and using "const" and "let".
The examples are below.

I also have the code block below that worked without the closure.

Tree that I feed in as a parameter

```
let u = [
  {
    id: 0,
    label: 'l0',
    children: [
      {
        id: 1,
        label: 'l1'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        label: 'l2',
        children: [
          {
            id: 3,
            label: 'l3'
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            label: 'l4'
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            label: 'l5'
          },
          {
            id: 6,
            label: 'l6',
            children: [
              {
                id: 7,
                label: 'l7'
              },
              {
                id: 8,
                label: 'l8'
              },
              {
                id: 9,
                label: 'l9'
              },
              {
                id: 10,
                label: 'l10'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

WHAT DID WORK

```
let branch_queue = [];
// Assumes that the ID exists!
const exploreNode = (nodeIdOfInterest, nodeTree) => {
    // var branch_queue = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < nodeTree.length; i++) {
        const nodeToCheck = nodeTree[i];
        if (nodeToCheck.id == nodeIdOfInterest) {
            branch_queue.push(nodeToCheck.id);
            return nodeToCheck.label;
        } else if(nodeToCheck.children) {
            branch_queue.push(nodeToCheck.id);
            return exploreNode(nodeIdOfInterest, nodeToCheck.children);
        }
    }
}

exploreNode(3, contentTree);
console.log(branch_queue); // prints the correct roadmap
```

WHAT DOESN'T WORK
ES5

```
function fn (nodeIdOfInterest, nodeTree) {
  let branch_queue = [];
  console.log('here');

  // Assumes that the ID exists!
  function exploreNode () {
      var branch_queue = [];
      console.log('in here');

      for (var i = 0; i < nodeTree.length; i++) {
          var nodeToCheck = nodeTree[i];
          console.log(`${nodeToCheck.label} : ${nodeToCheck.id}`);
          if (nodeToCheck.id == nodeIdOfInterest) {
              console.log('found it');

              branch_queue.push(nodeToCheck.id);
              return nodeToCheck.label;
          } else if(nodeToCheck.children) {
              console.log('checking children');
              branch_queue.push(nodeToCheck.id);
              return exploreNode(nodeIdOfInterest, nodeToCheck.children);
          }
      }
  };

  exploreNode();

  return branch_queue;
}

console.log(fn(3, contentTree)); // throws call stack error
```

ES6

```
const fn = (nodeIdOfInterest, nodeTree) => {
  let branch_queue = [];
  console.log('here');

  // Assumes that the ID exists!
  const exploreNode = () => {
      // var branch_queue = [];
      console.log('in here');

      for (let i = 0; i < nodeTree.length; i++) {
          let nodeToCheck = nodeTree[i];
          console.log(`${nodeToCheck.label} : ${nodeToCheck.id}`);
          if (nodeToCheck.id == nodeIdOfInterest) {
              branch_queue.push(nodeToCheck.id);
              return nodeToCheck.label;
          } else if(nodeToCheck.children) {
              branch_queue.push(nodeToCheck.id);
              return exploreNode(nodeIdOfInterest, nodeToCheck.children);
          }
      }
  };

  exploreNode();

  return branch_queue;
};
console.log(fn(3, contentTree)); // throws call stack error
```

Expected output => [0 2 3]
Actual => . Max call stack error

The recursive function never moves beyond the very first level, and repeats indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nodeTree` in your recursive version of `exploreNode` is always the same starting point, the one passed into `fn`. Every call to `exploreNode` in that version starts fresh: Your calls to `exploreNode` are passing arguments, but it's ignoring them. The "what did work" version isn't ignoring the arguments passed to it, so it works.

Comment: if this isn't the dumbest mistake I've ever made.

Comment: Thank you so much @T.J Crowder. Appreciate the fast reply!